# Hex 2's complement missing leading 0 when original decimal is a digit short

Tags: python, pandas, hex

Sample of my data:

| osiId | timeFrameEnd | hostUnits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3858201547035376271 | 2022-10-24 23:00:00 | 3.922447 |
| 688220028058186626 | 2022-10-24 23:00:00 | 0.969557 |
| 4711727337820221419 | 2022-10-24 23:00:00 | 1.959828 |

Notice row 2 osiId is a digit short of rows 1 and 3.

I use the following code to convert the osiId's to hex 2's complements:

```
def tohex(val, nbits):
  return hex((val + (1 << nbits)) % (1 << nbits))
```

Which works and returns the following (ignore the "0x" in front):

| osiId | timeFrameEnd | hostUnits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x358b15dd8ae7fa8f | 2022-10-24 23:00:00 | 3.922447 |
| 0x98d0c781bb7b382 | 2022-10-24 23:00:00 | 0.969557 |
| 0x41636b0cc9456feb | 2022-10-24 23:00:00 | 1.959828 |

Now according to this [site](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html).

The second rows hex 2's complement should be: 098D0C781BB7B382

I'm missing that first 0.

Rows 1 and 3 convert just fine, the only difference between the rows is that row 2 is a digit short in both tables. In my real data this happens again with another row that is also a digit short.

I know nothing about hexadecimals, anyone have any insights into this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have strings, you can use:

```
df['osiId'] = df['osiId'].str[2:].str.zfill(df['osiId'].str.len().max()-2)
```

output:

```
              osiId         timeFrameEnd  hostUnits
0  358b15dd8ae7fa8f  2022-10-24 23:00:00   3.922447
1  098d0c781bb7b382  2022-10-24 23:00:00   0.969557
2  41636b0cc9456feb  2022-10-24 23:00:00   1.959828
```

Or, if you want to keep the '0x':

```
df['osiId'] = '0x' + df['osiId'].str[2:].str.zfill(df['osiId'].str.len().max()-2)
```

output:

```
                osiId         timeFrameEnd  hostUnits
0  0x358b15dd8ae7fa8f  2022-10-24 23:00:00   3.922447
1  0x098d0c781bb7b382  2022-10-24 23:00:00   0.969557
2  0x41636b0cc9456feb  2022-10-24 23:00:00   1.959828
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'osiId': [3858201547035376271, 688220028058186626, 4711727337820221419],
                   'timeFrameEnd': ['2022-10-24 23:00:00', '2022-10-24 23:00:00', '2022-10-24 23:00:00'],
                   'hostUnits': [3.922447, 0.969557, 1.959828]})

def tohex(val, nbits):
  return hex((val + (1 << nbits)) % (1 << nbits))

df['osiId'] = df['osiId'].apply(tohex, nbits=2**int(np.ceil(np.log10(df['osiId'])).max()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
df['osiId'] = df['osiId'].str[2:].str.zfill(df['osiId'].str.len().max()-2) works perfectly. Why is that last line of code different? Just a different way to calculate the same thing?

Comment: Which last line? If you're talking about the `Used input` part, this is just to provide a reproducible input for whoever would like to try to reproduce it